# How to embed a <video> tag using Javascript in bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to embed a video in a bootstrap modal for an assignment and I haven't a clue why I cant get it to work.

I tried this iteration

```
<h3 id = "giza_Pyramid" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pyramid";>The Giza Pyramids</h3>
                            <p> 
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit culpa eligendi enim suscipit voluptatibus consequatur pariatur aut incidunt quo dicta, cumque quidem iste recusandae esse explicabo modi voluptatem, eum optio.
                            </p>
<script>
if (
  document
    .querySelector("#giza_Pyramid")
    .addEventListener("click", function () {
      document.querySelector("#modal_body").textContent = (
        <video class ="giza_Pyramid" width = "450" height = "350" controls src= "Media/gizapyramids.mp4"></video>
      );
    })
);
</script>
```

This is basically what I'm using to make it work but when I try it I get a error shown below.
`Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`

Any advice on any other functions I can try that would be able to help

Comment: You need to use innerHTML, `document.querySelector("#modal_body").innerHTML= "   <video class ="giza_Pyramid" width = "450" height = "350" controls src= "Media/gizapyramids.mp4"></video>";`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
document.getElementById("giza_Pyramid").addEventListener("click", function () {
      document.querySelector("#modal_body").innerHTML = '<video class ="giza_Pyramid" width = "450" height = "350" controls src= "Media/gizapyramids.mp4"></video>';
    })
```

Reason to use the **innerHTML** because the contain have the HTML tags.

Thanks.

Comment: I ran into a second issue where all the text in modal body has been switched to the video only, What steps should I take in order to place the video at the bottom of the text?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting `textContent`, set `innerHTML` of the modal body directly like this:

```
<h3 id="giza_Pyramid" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pyramid">The Giza Pyramids</h3>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit culpa eligendi enim suscipit voluptatibus consequatur pariatur aut incidunt quo dicta, cumque quidem iste recusandae esse explicabo modi voluptatem, eum optio.
</p>

<script>
  document.querySelector("#giza_Pyramid").addEventListener("click", function () {
    const modalBody = document.querySelector("#modal_body");
    modalBody.innerHTML = 
      <video class="giza_Pyramid" width="450" height="350" controls>
        <source src="Media/gizapyramids.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    ;
  });
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).